# Why Isn't NSUserDefaults working with my UISwitch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I'm trying to setup a UISwitch that is off by default until the user turns it on.  However it is showing ON by default now.

AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching:

```
NSString *testValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"pinCodeSwitch"];
if (!testValue) {
    // since no default values have been set, create them here
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"pinCodeSwitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

VC's viewDidAppear:

```
UISwitch* testSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"pinCodeSwitch"]) {
    [testSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
}
self.pinCodeSwitch = testSwitch;
```

Method to save BOOL when UISwitch's value changed:

```
- (IBAction)pinCodeSwitchChanged:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"pinCodeSwitch"];
    BOOL test = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"pinCodeSwitch"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting to set the switch since you set 'pinCodeSwitch' to NO.  It skips the if statement.
Change it to:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"pinCodeSwitch"])
```

(Negate your test), then the switch will turn off.

Comment: So I changed the code to `UISwitch* testSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"pinCodeSwitch"]) 
    [testSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
}
self.pinCodeSwitch = testSwitch;`.  It is still on when I load the vc.

Comment: Can you put a break point at the  [testSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO]; line?  Does your program hit that breakpoint?

Comment: Yup, it does hit that breakpoint.  In IB, the switch state is set to ON, but that shouldn't make a differenc cause the code should change it to off.

Comment: I'm stumped, that code should set it to off.  Is there any other code that is executed later that could switch it back.

Comment: I haven't yet implemented code what to save the new state one the value is changed.  All I have currently is the code I posted above in the app delegate, and this code in the actual VC.

Comment: It could also be how you're setting pin code switch at the end.  Try [self.pinCodeSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO]; instead of [testSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];  If you're using interface builder that will make the switch for you and you won't need to alloc/init a switch(like your testSwitch)

Comment: I think I got it working.  I changed the code to just `if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"pinCodeSwitch"]) 
    {
        [self.pinCodeSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
    }` and removed the `testSwitch` stuff

Comment: Can you check out the new method I added, how should I fix it so it saves the new value when the UISwitch is changed?

Comment: Looks ok to me.  But you'll have to remember to synchronize in order to save the defaults

Answer (score 1):

you can specify this value in the Interface Builder by the "STATE" value to OFF.
and after that save the switch value by applying this code:

```
[YourUiSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:YourUiSwitch forKey:@"youruiswitch"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

and when the view did load comes load it from the defaults like this:`YourUiSwitch =

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"youruiswitch"];`
```

GOOD LUCK BUDDY!

Comment: Yes, but should it load to NO because it has already been set in the App Delegate to NO?

Comment: This will set the switch to OFF because you're setting it in IB. Theres nothign to test because it doesn't really do anything.  You don't even have code to save it if value was changed to ON.

Comment: no. you will load the switch from the defaults on the viewdidload programatically and it will take over the IB settings

Comment: But where does it save the state when i switch the UISwitch to ON?

Comment: when you save the switch to the defaults you are also save all of his property setting. so when you load it you load the settings as well

Comment: Can you please provide the full code? How do I load it from [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"youruiswitch"];?

Comment: Got it working. Can you check out the new method I added, how should I fix it so it saves the new value when the UISwitch is changed?